# How to use WHERE IN clause with ogr2ogr

Tags: postgis, ogr, ogr2ogr, geopackage

I am exporting some tables from PostGIS to a geopackage. My command to do is task is as follows

```
ogr2ogr -append -f GPKG E:\workspace\test.gpkg PG:service=XXXX -where app_einzugsgebiet.hauptgemeinde=70346  app_einzugsgebiet -nln Einzugsgebiet -nlt MULTIPOLYGON -lco GEOMETRY_NAME=shape -a_srs EPSG:31287
```

Now, I would like to use the `WHERE IN` clause in my command. However, I could not figure out how. I tried the following command

```
ogr2ogr -append -f GPKG E:\workspace\test.gpkg PG:service=XXXX -where app_einzugsgebiet.hauptgemeinde IN (70319, 70101, 70346) app_einzugsgebiet -nln Einzugsgebiet -nlt MULTIPOLYGON -lco GEOMETRY_NAME=shape -a_srs EPSG:31287
```

I am getting an error that says `ERROR 1: Couldn't fetch requested layer 'IN'!`. I tried with square bracket but it did not help either.
Obviously, my syntax is not okay.
So how do I do that?